# Difference between return String from a method and string variable

Tags: java, string, expression, nashorn

I have this below piece of code,

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        Test ctrl = new Test();
        String[] arr = {"1==1"};
        String eer = "1==1";
        engine.put("hi", ctrl);
        System.out.println(engine.eval(arr[0])); //true
        System.out.println(engine.eval(eer)); //true
        System.out.println(engine.eval("hi.values()")); //prints 1==1
    }

    public String values() {
        return "1==1";
    }
}
```

I can understand the last `sout` statement is enclosed in double quotes hence it prints the value as it is.

How can i make the statement to evaluate the expression as 
like other string variables?

**EDIT**

In java if i add ,

```
String result = ctrl.values(); //returns 1==1
System.out.println(engine.eval(result));//true
```

I tried same on javascript

```
var result = myfun();
function myfun(){
return "1!=1";
}

if(result){
window.alert("yes"); // This came even when condition is false
}
```

Comment: Try `System.out.println(engine.eval("eval(hi.values())"));`

Comment: are you asking about javascript `eval`? https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/eval

Comment: For your javascript test you are returning a String "1!=1", so that will always evaluate to true, since it's not a boolean, it's a String. 1 != 1 without the quotes would evaluate to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i make the statement to evaluate the expression as like other string variables?

Why not `engine.eval()` twice?

```
System.out.println(engine.eval(engine.eval("hi.values()")));
```

> In java if i add , [some code that does something] I tried same on javascript [some identical-looking code that does a different thing]

There's no implicit call to `eval` in JavaScript. This means that `result` holds the **non-empty** string `1!=1`, which becomes `true` in an if-statement.